# Possible Malicious error Facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to link my website to my page but when it's clicked it brings up this error:

> Possible problem with this link We have detected that this link:
>   viqtory.win may be malicious. To keep your account and device secure,
>   only follow links you trust.

I have an SSL and ran the facebook debugger. All the documentation regarding this questions is from 3 years ago. Is there an updated solution for this problem? Is it because my website ends in a .win?

Comment: there is a security check if you really want to post it, and there is a "let us know" link you can follow.

Comment: Where do I find those? @luschn

Comment: just try to post it, there will be the link

Comment: Not an option. Only clickable options are "go back" or "Follow Link"

Comment: ok, i see a different version then, if i just try to post the domain directly on facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around.

Using a bitly link (bitly.com) and posting that seems to do the trick. Still don't understand why my website is being blocked but for the time being this works.